# two AES implementations generated different encryption results

Tags: c++, encryption, aes

I have an application that uses an opensource "libgcrypt" to encrypt/decrypt a data block (32 bytes). Now I am going to use Microsoft CryptAPI to replace it. My problem is that the libgcrypt and cryptApi approaches generate different ciphertext contents as I use the same AES-256 algoritjm in CFB  mode, same key, and same IV, although the ciphertext can be decrypted by their own correspndingly.

Could some tell me what is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do the two assume different endianness, or assign the bytes in the key/IV in different orders?

If the endianness assumptions are different, you may need to re-order the bytes in the key, IV and/or plaintext to get matching results. For example, if you are supplying bytes in the order `abcdefgh`, you may need to switch this to 'dcbahgfe' to get things to work.

Comment: I believe they have different endianness.

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional parameter for CFB, namely the "shift amount" at each iteration. The [Wikipedia page on CFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29) has some information. Namely, you encrypt *x* bits for every block encryption, where *x* is any value between 1 and the block size (128 for AES). I suspect that in your code, the Microsoft CryptoAPI and libgcrypt do not use the same value for *x*.

As explained in the documentation for [CryptSetKeyParam()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380272(VS.85).aspx), Windows defaults to *x=8* (i.e. one byte at a time). This is the `KP_MODE_BITS` parameter. On the other hand, libgcrypt [defaults to *x=n*](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Available-cipher-modes.html) for a *n*-bit block cipher (i.e. *x=128* for AES). I am not sure libgcrypt can be convinced to use another value.

Comment: Calling this CryptSetKeyParam() by passing value greater than 64 always returns 0 (fail), and this function call seems have no effect on the ciphertext contents when the mode-bits value is not more than 64 (probably because that fact that I only need to call the encryption function once in my application).

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is with block size .as you said you are using 32 byte as block size make sure if block size of both are same and supports as well .because some of library block size is fixed for Aes as 16 byte .

Answer (score 0):

What is the length of your key and IV?
Are ciphertexts different if the length of opentext is exactly 256 bit?

Comment: I can see where you're heading with this, but in CFB mode the cipher ought to be operating effectively as a stream cipher, with no padding...

Comment: The length of key is 32 bytes, and IV, 16 bytes.

The ciphertexts are different no matter the size of the opentext.

Comment: Re-orderring the bytes in the key, IV,  and/or plaintext, and trying all their combinations. No one is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, but with a different library. I noticed one thing in this library; If I pass input byte less than 32 bytes, in that case it's showing me both are the same encrypted data.

Is that what's happening in your case? If so, it means the problem is with the padding mechanism.